# Is it possible to assign a javascript value to a php variable?

Tags: php, javascript, blowfish

I have a (php) array of blowfish encrypted data posted from a form-submit. I have a blowfish algorithm in javascript.

```
var bf = new Blowfish('12345678901234567');
var ciphertext = bf.encrypt('test data');
alert(ciphertext);
var plaintext = bf.decrypt(ciphertext);
alert(plaintext);
```

I need to use this javascript blowfish code to decrypt the array of data and save the decrypted data in database.

How can I do this? Can the decrypted value from javascript be assigned to a php variable?
Pleas Help...

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt data in javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747186/how-to-assign-the-value-of-a-javascript-variable-to-a-php-variable

Comment: Exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+variable+to+php

Comment: I think that you're going to need an ajax call but I don't know how to do that in pure javascript.

Answer (score 3):

PHP is executed server-side (first, it then send the computed HTML etc. to the client), and JavaScript is executed client-side (last).

It would be possible to assign a PHP value to a javascript variable in a PHP file, for example  :

```
<?php
    $myValue = 42;
?>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var aVariable = <?=$myValue?>;
</script>
```

You can't do the opposite (what you asked).

What were you trying to do? Maybe we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Dont you just want to use blowfish in PHP? You can use the `crypt` function for that.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Answer (score 0):

as TJHeuvel above says you should be capturing the post variables in PHP on the SERVER side not processing with CLIENT side Javascript